# Read email and store values into database in php

Tags: php, database, email

I'm new to PHP, and with basic working knowledge. I have a requirement to read the email(gmail) and get the values in it and store them into database accordingly. But the problem is getting the values from email body. I can read the mail and display data using IMAP extension(Using [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch17_04.htm) as guide). But how to get the exact values from mail body. Basically mail has a table with values.

I don't know how to implement it. Let me know if this is a right method or is there any other methods to do this? I can do storing in database part.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should do this with Jquery or Javascript, (parsing the html)

Comment: Your question is very vague in what your actual task is. It is not possible to answer it in it's current form. Please add more details to your description. There is an `edit` link below your question for that. _Use it..._

Comment: It _might_ be that what you are trying to do is interpret the html body of an email message and, if it contains a certain table structure then pick the table cell values and store those in a database. For that you should use a DOM parser to "read" the message body. That allows you to iterate through the elements of the HTML structure and pick single values. But as said: your question is very vague, this is only a wild _guess_.

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki I don't see how client side logic should help here. Do you really suggest to implement an `imap` client and a database connector on the client side? _Why_, if it already exists for the server side in a perfectly usable way? And why chose a platform that requires an interactive work when the OP most likely wants to poll that email box on a regular basis to process incoming messages?

Comment: At least you need to add the message body content to your question. Without that, how do you expect anyone to suggest an implementation?

Comment: Sorry, here is code for reading mail,
`<?php 
$hostname = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX";
$username = "testmail@gmail.com";
$password = "password";
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
if($emails) {
$output = '';
rsort($emails);
foreach($emails as $email_number) {
 $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
 $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
 $body   = imap_body($inbox, $email_number);
}
echo $body;
}
imap_close($inbox);
?>`

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for your suggestion, That gave me some idea how to get the result.I'm getting the message as plain text by using `imap_fetchbody()` method and converted it to array.

Comment: For future questiin pleaae consider two things: 1. always add additional Details to the question itself, not to comments wäre they are not readable and 2. please add a full answer so that others finding your question can learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code that I used to get the result.

```
<?php
$hostname = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX";
$username = "testmail@gmail.com";
$password = "password";
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
if($emails) {
    $output = '';
    rsort($emails);
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {
        $message = (imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.1)); 
        if($message == '')
        {
            $message = (imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1));
        }
        $array = explode("\n", $message);
    }
    print_r($array);
}
imap_close($inbox);
?>
```